# Getting Maybe from lens with default value

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

A lot of lens getters return Maybe values. And i often need to replace them with some default.

Say map lookup but with default.

```
fromMaybe "" $ Map.fromList [(1,"Foo")] ^? at 1
```

Can this be written with lens syntax? Maybe something close to this:

```
Map.fromList [(1,"Foo")] ^? at 1.or ""
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
non :: Eq a => a -> Iso a (Maybe a)
```

`non foo` essentially does

```
 case someMaybe of
   Nothing -> foo
   Just a  -> a
```

In your case

```
 someMap ^. at 1 . non ""
```

Coincidentally, this is precisely the example of `non` the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non) give.

If you want to use this with `ix` you're out of luck, but you can always do

```
 -- Import Data.Monoid
 defaulting :: a -> s -> Getting (First a) s a -> a
 defaulting a s fold = fromMaybe a $ s ^? fold

 foo = defaulting 0 [1, 2, 3] $ ix 3 -- 0
```

Comment: Awesome thanks!. Works as i want. I wonder though why they named it non? Weird name. "or" would have been so much more clearer.

Comment: @VagifVerdi It's supposed to be a mapping of `a` without whatever value supplied to `Maybe a` so in that sense it makes a bit more sense

Comment: Hmm, turns out does not work in some cases. Works with ^. at, does not work with ^? ix. Is there a way to apply it somehow to ix?

Comment: @VagifVerdi I think not, this is a map from `Maybe a` to `a`, but `ix` relies on an underlying monoid do use for failure, so if it fails it will never even pass the result to `non`.

Comment: If I may ask, why are you using `ix`?

Comment: fromMaybe 0 (someList ^? ix 0._1)
i'm taking the first element of the list. BUt of course list can be empty.

Comment: @VagifVerdi Yes, nothing can compose with something like `ix` and save it from failing if I understand lens correctly since it's going to fail part way through the chain (as a demonstration, stick an `Debug.Trace.trace` in there and see that things aren't evaluated). So that's the bad news, the good news is you can just define a combinator to wrap around `fromMaybe foo $ quux ^? baz` trivially.